# Java: Getting a substring from a string starting after a particular character

Tags: java, string, substring

I have a string:

```
/abc/def/ghfj.doc
```

I would like to extract `ghfj.doc` from this, i.e. the substring after the last `/`, or first `/` from right.

Could someone please provide some help?

Comment: look, i understand the value of searching for the answer yourself before asking questions, but the fact of the matter is this question made my search much easier.. exactly what I wanted after the first hit.  Quicker than consulting javadocs.  It's good that this question is here.  Why the downvotes?

Comment: Although this is somewhat different from your original question: In your example org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils.getBaseName is much more reliable than doing your own string operations.

Comment: @Eric I completely agree with your comment as this was the first Google result for my question and the accepted answer is exactly what I needed to use.

Answer (score 398, accepted):

```java
String example = "/abc/def/ghfj.doc";
System.out.println(example.substring(example.lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
```

Answer (score 53):

A very simple implementation with [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)):

```
String path = "/abc/def/ghfj.doc";
// Split path into segments
String segments[] = path.split("/");
// Grab the last segment
String document = segments[segments.length - 1];
```

Comment: this code will throw an Array Index Out of Bounds error if the separator is not found.

Answer (score 44):

what have you tried?
it's very simple:

```
String s = "/abc/def/ghfj.doc";
s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)
```

Answer (score 37):

Another way is to use [this](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html).

```
String path = "/abc/def/ghfj.doc"
String fileName = StringUtils.substringAfterLast(path, "/");
```

If you pass null to this method it will return null. If there is no match with separator it will return empty string.

Comment: Finally something really handy, didn't know about this method. I hate to hassle with substring + indexof + 1 - 2 +3 whatsoever. This is much cleaner :)

Comment: If you want to use this method on Android, you have to import `StringUtils` library, this answer shows hot to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33935645/2966583

Answer (score 12):

You can use Apache commons:

For substring after last occurrence use [this](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#substringAfterLast(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method.

And for substring after first occurrence equivalent method is [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#substringAfter(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 8):

This can also get the filename

```
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Path;
Path path = Paths.get("/abc/def/ghfj.doc");
System.out.println(path.getFileName().toString());
```

Will print `ghfj.doc`

Answer (score 6):

In Kotlin you can use `substringAfterLast`, specifying a delimiter.

```
val string = "/abc/def/ghfj.doc"
val result = url.substringAfterLast("/")
println(result)
// It will show ghfj.doc
```

From the [doc](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/substring-after-last.html):

> Returns a substring after the last occurrence of delimiter. If the string does not contain the delimiter, returns missingDelimiterValue which defaults to the original string.

Answer (score 4):

With [Guava](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/23.6-jre) do this:

```
String id="/abc/def/ghfj.doc";
String valIfSplitIsEmpty="";
return Iterables.getLast(Splitter.on("/").split(id),valIfSplitIsEmpty);
```

Eventually configure the `Splitter` and use

```
Splitter.on("/")
.trimResults()
.omitEmptyStrings()
...
```

Also take a look into [this article on guava Splitter](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/StringsExplained#splitter) and [this article on guava Iterables](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained#iterables)

Comment: Note that this solution if not very effective due to creation of extra objects for every split point.

Comment: @Vadzim Correct. This should be considered. Also see this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42584477/should-guava-splitters-joiners-be-created-each-time-they-are-used

Answer (score 0):

I think that would be better if we use directly the split function

```
String toSplit = "/abc/def/ghfj.doc";

String result[] = toSplit.split("/");

String returnValue = result[result.length - 1]; //equals "ghfj.doc"
```

Comment: this code will throw an error if the separator is not found.

Comment: @PatrickParker Why have you commented everywhere that it will throw an error if the separator is not found. If you are doing it for knowledge purposes than okay, but  I just think it's a bit too much maybe...

Comment: @GauravMall I am helping people to improve their answers, to write better code, and for those who are visiting to help them avoid pitfalls and build understanding of the code before they paste it somewhere. I will gladly remove my comment once the answer is improved. Also, writing it in two places is hardly "everywhere". Finally, the comment section is not for meta discussion.

Answer (score 0):

**java android**

in my case

I want to change from

> ~/propic/........png

anything after **/propic/** doesn't matter what before it

> ........png

finally, I found the code in [Class StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html)

this is the code

```
     public static String substringAfter(final String str, final String separator) {
         if (isEmpty(str)) {
             return str;
         }
         if (separator == null) {
             return "";
         }
         final int pos = str.indexOf(separator);
         if (pos == 0) {
             return str;
         }
         return str.substring(pos + separator.length());
     }
```

Comment: `substringAfter("abc", "a") == "abc"` this doesn't work as original substring after