# how to extract first substring i a string containg /?

Tags: java, substring

I would like to extract `ccadmin` from `/ccadmin/hrp/filelist` ?

i know that i can get last substring using

```
String uri = "/ccadmin/hrp/filelist";
String commandKey = uri.substring(uri.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, uri.length());
```

but how to extract first Substring `ccadmin`?

Comment: We need more details. What are the assumptions?  Can we assume the string you are parsing will always be the same format?

Comment: Also a possible duplicate of [Java: Getting a substring from a string starting after a particular character](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14316487/3224483), which is actually in Java.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand your question, then you could use something like,

```
String uri = "/ccadmin/hrp/filelist";
String first = uri.substring(1, uri.indexOf("/", 2));
System.out.println(first);
```

Output is

```
ccadmin
```

Answer (score 3):

Split the string by the / character:

```
String[] parts = uri.split("/");
```

parts[1] is what you want.

Comment: This has the unfortunate side effect of doing a bunch of unnecessary work.

Comment: @pamphlet, can you please explain what you mean?

Comment: @pamphlet true, the easiest solution is usually not the most efficient one

Comment: Sure. This will split the entire uri, creating multiple strings. Of which only one is required. The generation of all those other strings is a waste. Elliott's solution doesn't suffer from this problem.

Comment: @RockOnRockOut Amen to that.

Comment: @Pshemo yeah, you were right, sorry. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to split your string and then get the part of uri you need:

```
String uri = "/s/d/f";
        String[] parts = uri.split("/");
        String item = parts[1];
        System.out.println( item );
```