# Java/Android: StringUtils.countMatches alternative for Android?

Tags: java, android

I want to count the number of times a character occurs in a string. I've found the one-liner:

`int count = StringUtils.countMatches("a.b.c.d", ".");`

However, Android Studio doesn't support `StringUtils`. I know it's possible to do:

`int count = "a.b.c.d".length() - "a.b.c.d".replace(".", "").length();`

But I was wondering: does Android have a built-in function for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**gradle:**

```
   dependencies {
      ...
      implementation  'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0'
      ...
   }
```

**java:**

```
  import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
```

from now you should be able to use:

```
  int count = StringUtils.countMatches("a.b.c.d", ".");
```

Answer (score 2):

I native java code you can use :

```
int count = s.length() - s.replace(".", "").length();
```

Very simple, but useful if you don't want to include other lib to your project.

Comment: Thanks! But I know that's possible, I already gave that example in my opening post :-)

Comment: Smart - great idea. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for your integer variable.

> int number = org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.countMatches(input, "a");

Follow this **link :** http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/12/how-to-count-occurrence-of-character-in-String.html

**Cheers!!**