# return substring within an array

Tags: arrays, groovy, substring, lastindexof

I found a good solution but not exactly for my problem:

```
String s = "abc.def.ghfj.qert"; 
s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(".") + 1)
```

Source:
[Java: Getting a substring from a string starting after a particular character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14316487/java-getting-a-substring-from-a-string-starting-after-a-particular-character/38148477#38148477)

This I have to use it within an array, but I have NO idea how to do... sorry.

I got the following code:

```
a = [];
b=getLinkedItems(item("link_M"))
for(i in 0..b.size()-1)
{ a[i] = b.getAt(i).toString().reverse().substring(0,1) }
total = 0
for(x in a) { total = total +","+x }
val = total.substring(2)
```

This is my result:

```
[b] = [java.util.ArrayList] [

Group:m.1:book1150:MGROUP.6/M/m.1, 

Group:m.6:book1150:MGROUP.6/M/m.6, 

Group:m.9:book1150:MGROUP.6/M/m.9]

[a] = [java.util.ArrayList] [1, 6, 9]

[total] = "0,1,6,9"

[val] = "1,6,9"
```

... but it is not practicable if my array contains a value greater than 9.

```
What can I do if my array is e.g.: 

[b] = [java.util.ArrayList] [

Group:m.1:book1150:MGROUP.6/M/m.1, 

Group:m.6:book1150:MGROUP.6/M/m.6, 

Group:m.9:book1150:MGROUP.6/M/m.12]
```

and my result should be:

```
[val] = "1,6,12"
```

Who can help me? Where do I have to write e.g. "lastIndexOf(".")" or do anyone have a better solution?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using regular expressions instead, and maybe some `List`-based mix-ins for good measure. Something like this maybe:

```
def b = getLinkedItems(item("link_M"))
def a = b.collect { (it.toString() =~ /\d+$/)[0] }
def val = a.join(",")
def total = "0," + val
```

In this, `b.collect` runs the `Closure` that follows once for each element of `b`, returning a `List` of results to assign to `a`. The find (`=~`) operator returns a `Matcher` object that finds all instances of the regular expression on the right (`/\d+$/` in this case) within the source `String` on the left. The matched values can be retrieved from the `Matcher` by indexing it like a `List`. Then on the next line, `a.join(",")` joins together all the elements of `a` with `,` as a separator.

The regular expression `/\d+$/` means:

- `\d+` any substring of one or more digits
- `$` at the end of the source `String`

Comment: GREAT!! This is EXACTLY what I need. Thank you soooo much! :-) This is my desired result of val: Return Value: "1,6,12"

Comment: Great, glad to help. Not to be pushy, but are you going to select my answer then?

Comment: You're not pushy, I am new and did not read completely the instructions how to select the correct answer...

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax in the question is confusing, but assuming you mean you have:

```
def list = [
    'Group:m.1:book1150:MGROUP.6/M/m.1', 
    'Group:m.6:book1150:MGROUP.6/M/m.6', 
    'Group:m.9:book1150:MGROUP.6/M/m.12'
]
```

then you can just do:

```
def val = list.collect { row -> row.findAll(/\d+/)[-1] }.join(',')
```

For the bintan Group stuff, try:

```
def val = list.collect { row -> row.toString().findAll(/\d+/)[-1] }.join(',')
```

Comment: My syntax was correct copied. When I try your code I get this response: Error: No signature of method: bintan.form.Group.findAll() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [\d+]

Comment: WTH is `bintan.form.Group`?

Comment: I would guess that `bintan.form.Group` is the actual type returned by his `getLinkedItems` method, since that is the only place a `findAll` is used in your code.

Comment: @PegasusTT77 added a `toString()` call to the collect

Comment: How are you handling strings that end in multi-digit numbers? `[-1]` will only grab the last digit.

Comment: It will grab the last result from `findAll`, which is looking for `\d+`

Comment: Yes, but you are only taking the last character, (index `[-1]`), so it doesn't matter what the findAll expression matches. if the `String` value of his element were `"Group:m.9:book1150:MGROUP.6/M/m.12"`, you would only return `2`, not `12`.

Comment: @tim_yates: My system works based on Groovy language (eclipse). I am sorry that I did not write it within my question.

Comment: @BalRog no it doesn't...have you tried it?  `assert "Group:m.9:book1150:MGROUP.6/M/m.12".findAll(/\d+/)[-1] == '12'`

Comment: @tim_yates: Now it worked with your correction of "bintan Group stuff". :-)Sorry, I told I am a new user. Shame on me.

Comment: @PegasusTT77 No worries :-) I missed the `toString` in your question...  Glad you got it sorted :-)