# How to get the string value after the colon?

Tags: javascript, string

I really need your help,

How can I check a string to see if it has a ":" and then if it does, to get the string value after the ":"

ie.

```
var x = "1. Search - File Number: XAL-2017-463288"

var y = "XAL-2017-463288"
```

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14316487/java-getting-a-substring-from-a-string-starting-after-a-particular-character

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//check for the colon
if (x.indexOf(':') !== -1) {
  //split and get
  var y = x.split(':')[1];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Split on the colon, and grab the second member of the result. This assumes you want the first colon found.

```
var y = x.split(":")[1];
```

If the string didn't have a `:`, then `y` will be `undefined`, so a separate check isn't needed.

---

Or you could use `.indexOf()`. This assumes there's definitely a colon. Otherwise you'll get the whole string.

```
var y = x.slice(x.indexOf(":") + 1);
```

If you wanted to check for the colon, then save the result of `.indexOf()` to a variable first, and only do the `.slice()` if the index was not `-1`.

Comment: Also (for BobbyJones), [`<string>.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) can be used to remove the leading and trailing whitespace.