# JAVA SimpleDateFormat Error 2 Digit Year

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

Im trying to validate a date in java, everything works great except that it doesnt let me put a 2 digit year. I tried using "yyyy" in the format and "y" too, but doesnt work.

EDIT: some people misunderstood what i meant. what i want to get is input a date "1/1/55" and get the date "1/1/55" instead of "1/1/1955", so I'm not going to use "yy" as a date format, even if you can change the century i want to put a year of more than 2 digits too.

The problem is in the validation (if). The TestDate is the parsed of FechaString, but when i compare both, the value of testDate is for example "1/1/0055" when FechaString is "1/1/55", and it doesnt recognize them as equal.

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/y");
        Date testDate = null;
        String FechaString;
        int dia,mes,anno;
        boolean error=false;

        do{

        System.out.println("Introduzca la fecha de nacimiento (dd/mm/aaaa)");
        FechaString = entrada.nextLine();
        try{
            testDate = df.parse(FechaString);
        } catch (ParseException e){ System.out.println("Formato no válido");}

        if (!df.format(testDate).equals(FechaString)){
            System.out.println("\nFECHA NO PERMITIDA!!");
            error=true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("\nFecha: OK");
            error=false;
        }
        }while (error);

        FechaNac = df.parse(FechaString);
```

Comment: maybe try `yy` for a 2 digit year

Comment: It doesnt work, because it takes the relative date with this century, if you put for example "33" it takes 1933 as year

Comment: well, that is a special case which you then have to handle yourself somehow. until 2018 you can use `yy`

Comment: If I enter, say, 70, what result do you want? Year 70, year 1970 or year 2070? And what do you get?

Comment: What did your research bring up? There are plenty of questions about parsing 2-digit year with `SimpleDateFormat` already. Please try them first and tell us how it went before we waste our time answering a question that has been answered a number of times before. Thank you.

Comment: The result that i want is to put 55 and get year 55, not 1955... i get an error when i put "yyyy"/"yyy" or "y" in the format, but i dont get the error whit "yy" because it gets the 1955, that is what i DONT want. i spotted the problem. in the condition where compares the format date with the input date it takes 0055 as year, when the input year still just 55.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: As Ole V.V. commented, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: @PixelFox You really want to record **the year 55, as in 1,963 years ago**? If so, just use an integer number. The date-time classes are intended for modern times, with issues of Julian/Gregorian cutover and other historical  matters. It is hard to think of a use-case where tracking a month and day-of-month thousands of years ago would make sense.

Comment: If you can have year 55 in the common era, can you have year 55 before the common era too? Have you got a way of distinguishing?

Answer (score 3):

Look at the [setTwoDigitYearStart](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#set2DigitYearStart%28java.util.Date%29) method with `yy` as the year term. You need to tell it which century you want the year to be considered as.

Answer (score 2):

As per java [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#year)

> For parsing with the abbreviated year pattern ("y" or "yy"),
>   SimpleDateFormat must interpret the abbreviated year relative to some
>   century. It does this by adjusting dates to be within 80 years before
>   and 20 years after the time the SimpleDateFormat instance is created.
>   For example, using a pattern of "MM/dd/yy" and a SimpleDateFormat
>   instance created on Jan 1, 1997, the string "01/11/12" would be
>   interpreted as Jan 11, 2012 while the string "05/04/64" would be
>   interpreted as May 4, 1964. During parsing, only strings consisting of
>   exactly two digits, as defined by Character.isDigit(char), will be
>   parsed into the default century. Any other numeric string, such as a
>   one digit string, a three or more digit string, or a two digit string
>   that isn't all digits (for example, "-1"), is interpreted literally.
>   So "01/02/3" or "01/02/003" are parsed, using the same pattern, as Jan
>   2, 3 AD. Likewise, "01/02/-3" is parsed as Jan 2, 4 BC.

So, the behavior has explained clearly in docs. However, you can change it setting of default `century` by using `SimpleDateFormat#set2DigitYearStart()` this method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use yy instead of y.

```
**SimpleDateFormat s=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
        String format = s.format(new Date());
     System.out.println(format);**
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want comes straight out of `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. Let me demonstrate:

```
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d/M/u");

    for (String dateString : new String[] { "1/1/5", "1/1/55", "1/1/755", "1/1/1955" }) {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateString, dtf);
        System.out.println(date);
        String formattedBack = date.format(dtf);
        System.out.println(formattedBack);
        System.out.println("Equal to original string? " + formattedBack.equals(dateString));
    }
```

This prints

```
0005-01-01
1/1/5
Equal to original string? true
0055-01-01
1/1/55
Equal to original string? true
0755-01-01
1/1/755
Equal to original string? true
1955-01-01
1/1/1955
Equal to original string? true
```

The modern API is (also generally) much nicer to work with. So I suggest that you throw the troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and the other outdated date-time classes overboard.

Only thing to notice is that the modern classes use the Proleptic Gregorian calendar. Its dates do not always coincide with the Julian calendar used for old dates by the old-fashioned classes.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Wikipedia article: Proleptic Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar)

Answer (score 0):

@PixelFox The Simple date format should be like this `"dd/MM/yyyy"`

try this hope its helps...

import

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

 try {
        SimpleDateFormat simpledate = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        testDate = df.parse(FechaString);
        if (!FetchString.equals(sdf.format(testdate))) {
            testdate = null;
        }else{}
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: That is the same format as the one i use, but in the one you say you have to put 0 to enter the 1 digit days and months

Comment: i tried it, but when i put a 2 digit year it gets the relative to this century. i editted the question, read it again to see what i want to get

Comment: only way you use substring method 1 find the occurence of "/" then check whether it has two digits after the occurrence  of "/" then replace to year format

Comment: have look it may helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14316487/java-getting-a-substring-from-a-string-starting-after-a-particular-character

Comment: @Sukesh There ought to be no need for taking out substrings or splitting using regular expressions. A good date-time formatter used correctly can do all that’s needed.